# How do you fix PhantomJs's lack of bind error?

Tags: phantomjs

Just crawling a web page like github.com I hit the famous `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://github.com', function() {
  phantom.exit();
});
```

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/r0hPOmnCUpc/uxusqsl2LNoJ

So exactly how do you fix this problem for someone totally new to PhantomJS?

Do I git clone [curjojs/poly](https://github.com/cujojs/poly) and then wrap all my PhantomJS code under `poly/function` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/19521355/230884?

I don't see any official documentation on solving this particular issue.

Comment: Yeah your need to shim bind. PhantomJS is built with QTwebkit and it doesnt support bind.